# Virtual environment cannot find scipy

Tags: python, scipy, virtualenv

I am just setting up python and PyCharm on a new Mac. I have some code that I want to run that uses numpy and scipy. Using the terminal, I created a virtual environment and activated it:
`source ~/PycharmProjects/TernaryTest/venv/bin/activate`.

I navigated to this environment in the PyCharm IDE, tried running my program (which imports numpy but not yet scipy), and had an error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`.

At this point, I returned to the terminal, navigated to the virtual environment and activated it, and ran:
`pip3 install numpy`. The program runs in PyCharm without a problem. Now I modify the code to also require that scipy be imported:

```
import numpy
import scipy
...
```

Same `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'`. I repeat the process that worked for numpy, but continue to get the same error.

Attempting to use pip3 additional times in the virtual environment to obtain scipy results in:

```
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in ./PycharmProjects/TernaryTest/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in ./PycharmProjects/TernaryTest/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scipy) (1.18.1)
```

In addition, scipy appears in the PyCharm IDE as being installed in the site-packages directory, right alongside numpy. Restarting various programs does not result in any improved behaviour.

Can someone please help me rectify this situation? Thanks!

Comment: What are the commands that you ran in the terminal?

Comment: @iBug The virtual environment activation command and installation command are mentioned above. Other than that, I only used basic stuff to navigate around, etc. The one thing that seems to be missing from my explanation is the set-up of the environment, but I think this was done automatically by PyCharm. Is there anything else you had in mind?

Comment: @iBug FYI here is the full appearance of the terminal when I try to install scipy: ```(venv) chris@Christophers-MacBook-Pro venv % pip3 install scipy```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not a satisfying answer, but is how I got the code to run:

```
deactivate venv
pip3 install scipy
```

Then, I re-activate venv and the code works. Admittedly, this doesn't make a lot of sense as I needed scipy in the virtual environment but had to exit the environment for the installation to be successful.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to force ?

```
pip3 install --force-reinstall scipy
```

Comment: Perhaps this is the correct answer, but unfortunately I cannot really test it as I got the code to work as above (I could perhaps uninstall scipy everywhere and try your method, but this seems like asking for trouble.) Thanks for the reply!